# Calling Solr Scheme API using Solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Based on documentation 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API

I want to call Solr Scheme API using Solrj.
Following is curl command that i want to call from SolrJ

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name":"sell-by",
     "type":"tdate",
     "stored":true }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema
```

**Is there a way to call   using SolrJ ?**

Comment: which version of solrj you have?

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
    String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted";
    SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();


    Map<String, Object> fieldAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    fieldAttributes.put("name", "sell-by");
    fieldAttributes.put("type", "tdate");
    fieldAttributes.put("stored", true);

    SchemaRequest.AddField addFieldUpdateSchemaRequest =
            new SchemaRequest.AddField(fieldAttributes);
    SchemaResponse.UpdateResponse addFieldResponse = addFieldUpdateSchemaRequest.process(solr);
```

Some other code samples on working with Solr Schema API can be found in [SchemaTest.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solrj/src/test/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/SchemaTest.java) file.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is via [SchemaAPI](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/schema/SchemaRequest.html) in SolrJ (since Solr 5.3):

```
CloudSolrClient client = ...;
SchemaRequest request = new SchemaRequest();
SchemaResponse response = request.process(client, "collectionName");
SchemaRepresentation schema = response.getSchemaRepresentation();
```