# Create a collection (including schema.xml and config.xml) in SOLR from SOLRJ

Tags: solr, solrj

I am currently trying to make a system in which I can create a collection in solr based on a JSON schema I have. I want to do it all programmatically.

Comment: See the answer given by arghtype here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54188896/137650

Comment: @MatsLindh the above answers suggests ways for modifying a managed schema. But I am not sure if it lets us create a new schema for a new collection.

Comment: You create the configset by using the configset API to create a new, empty configuration (based on whatever you need as the default configuration - might just be an id field), then you create it through the Schema API after that.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks so much, your comments cleared my approach, I have got this up and working, will post a clean solution in few days.

Answer (score 0):

Plese refer the below code to create a new collection using solrj api.

```
final String[] solrUrl = { "http://localhost:8983/solr" };
 final CloudSolrClient cloudSolrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(Arrays.asList(solrUrl)).build();
 final String collectionName = "collection2";

    final int numShards = 2;
    final int numReplicas = 2;
    final int maxShardsPerNode = 2;
    final String solrZKConfigName = "_default";

    public String createCollection(){
        final CollectionAdminRequest.Create adminRequest = CollectionAdminRequest.Create
                .createCollection(collectionName, solrZKConfigName, numShards, numReplicas)
                .setMaxShardsPerNode(maxShardsPerNode);

        CollectionAdminResponse adminResponse = adminRequest.process(cloudSolrClient);

        System.out.println(adminResponse);
    }

    cloudSolrClient.close();
```